# How can I create a Shared-element Transition Listener in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am using shared element transitions between my activities, and I want to delay some UI updates until after the shared element transition from ActivityA to ActivityB is complete.

I am writing the app in Kotlin, and can't seem to be able to use any solutions converted from java. I have tried

```
val sharedElementEnterTransition = window.sharedElementEnterTransition
sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(object : Transition.TransitionListener() {
    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {
        super.onTransitionResume(transition)
    }
    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {
        super.onTransitionPause(transition)
    }
    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {
        super.onTransitionCancel(transition)
    }
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
        super.onTransitionStart(transition)
    }
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
        super.onTransitionEnd(transition)
    }
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return super.equals(other)
    }
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return super.hashCode()
    }
    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString()
    }
})
```

in `onCreate` in ActivityB, but get a type mis-match:

```
Error:(80, 51) Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided> but Transition.TransitionListener! was expected
```

and this for each `super` call

```
Error:(98, 24) Abstract member cannot be accessed directly
```

which I can't manage to resolve.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you add the error output? I don't see anything in your code that looks like a type mismatch.

Comment: I have now added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type mismatch you're seeing is between the `android.transition.Transition.TransitionListener` and `android.transition.support.Transition.TransitionListener` classes. (Or at least, this is how I am able to reproduce this issue).

`window.sharedElementEnterTransition` returns an object of the first `Transition` type, and you are trying to pass an instance of the second type. Because TransitionListener is an interface and one doesn't extend the other, they are not interchangeable. Simply change your import to remove the `support` package and this should compile and work.

Note that since this isn't support anymore, it's not backwards compatible. I am not familiar enough with transitions to tell you how to convert that `window` accessor into a compat version.